# Build failed with an exception VS 2015 Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, release

After install plugin etc. pushwoosh and run Release (create.apk file) get error.

http://prnt.sc/b85hvw

Any solution how solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the plugin. It needs these dependencies:

1. Android Support Repository
2. Android Support Library
3. Google Play Services
4. Google Repository
5. Google play Billing Library

Check this link: [Build error with message "Not found com.google.android....](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs#4-build-error-with-message-not-found-comgoogleandroidgmsplay-services-ads)

Installing these dependencies in your Android SDK Manager will solve the problem.